# mysql_num_rows Returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble using the `mysql_num_rows`. Using it and echo'ing the variables output returns a blank output, even when i know for sure there is a result (as it's displayed on the screen)

```php
 <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password1","db1");   
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM requested_Bookings 
        WHERE status = 'Accepted' AND room = 'Red'        ");
        echo '<h5> The following are todays confirmed bookings:</h5>';

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);    

        echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
        echo '</br>';
```

Using the following code, and further use of echo to output the results of the query, all the information from the row is displayed, but the value of `num_rows` doesn't show up.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` belongs to the deprecated *mysql* extension. You are using the modern *mysqli* extension for everything else. You want this one ~ http://php.net/manual/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Dont mix `mysqli_` with `mysql_` functions use one or other

Comment: You're mixing libraries. `mysql != mysqli`

Comment: Not sure how i managed to miss such a glaring error, but thanks for the comments.